# Creating sub dictionaries from unorganised csv and existing dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file indicating (in order) name, grade, name of lesson skipped, number of times, which I have parsed into a list of lists.

```py
csvlist = [['name','grade','lesson','number'],
           ['Jade','8','English','1'],
           ['James','7','Maths','3']...]
```

I already have a dictionary that has all grade 8 students names as keys and total number of skipped classes and gpa as a sub dictionary,

```py
names_dic = {'Jade':{'skip':2,'gpa':8.34}, 
             'Mark':{'skip':16,'gpa':5.67'},
              ...}
```

now I want to create a dictionary that used the same keys as `names_dic`, and links them to their respective names of lesson skipped and number of times. The problem is that, in the csv a person that has skipped the same lesson more than once it is written in multiple rows (do the number doesn't indicate necessarily the total amount of hours skipped for that specific lesson).

What I tried is:

```py
lesson = {}
keys = names_dic.keys()
subkeys = []
subvalues = []
number = 0
subkeys.append(crimes_list[1][2])
for i in crimes_list[1:]:
    for key in mykeys:
        sub_dic = {}
        if i[0] in keys:
            if i[2] not in subkeys:
                subkeys.append(i[2])
                number += int(i[3])
                subvalues.append(valcount)
            else:
                number += int(i[3])
        else:
            pass
        lesson[key] = sub_dic
lesson = dict(zip(keys, subvalues))
```

The expected output is:

```py
lesson = {'Jade':{'English':1,'Physics':1}, 
          'Mark':{'French':3,'Biology':5,'English':2,'Geography':3,'PE':3}
          ..}
```

I cannot figure out how to do this. I've been at it for days now but don't understand how I can iterate through the csv and link the correct sum to the right lesson and name. I'm sure there are packages that can do this very easily, but I'm new to python so I'm struggling.

Comment: Could you share part of the .csv file and also show the expected result?

Comment: I can't show the csv, but it has been parsed and shows the information in order. I am editing the question now

Comment: @Raphael I have edited it

Comment: Could you put in your .csv the following statement: "The problem is that, in the csv a person that has skipped the same lesson more than once it is written in multiple rows (do the number doesn't indicate necessarily the total amount of hours skipped for that specific lesson)." ?

Comment: @Raphael Basically in the csv if, say, mark has skipped French 3 times, I would get a row saying: Mark 8 French 1, and another row saying: Mark 8 French 2. So what I need to do is indicate that if the same subject is repeated multiple times for the same person, I need to add the numbers up

Comment: OK, I think I understand. The part "(do the number doesn't indicate necessarily the total amount of hours skipped for that specific lesson)" was confusing because you speak in number of times and later you speak in hours.

Comment: @Raphael yes sorry, I meant them as interchangeable, 1 time is 1 hour

Comment: Please take a look at the answer and tell me if that's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Using json and defaultdict

```py
import json
import collections
nested_dict = lambda: collections.defaultdict(nested_dict)

csvlist = [['name','grade','lesson','number'],
           ['Jade','8','English',1],
           ['Jade','8','English',3],
           ['Jade','8','French',4],
           ['James','7','Maths',3]]

names_dic = {'Jade':{'skip':2,'gpa':8.34}, 
             'Mark':{'skip':16,'gpa':5.67}}

lesson = nested_dict()
min_grade = 8

for student in csvlist[1:]:
    student_name = student[0]
    student_grade = student[1]
    student_lesson = student[2]
    student_number = student[3]
  
    # if the key exists add the number
    if float(student_grade) >= min_grade:
        if lesson[student_name][student_lesson]:
            lesson[student_name][student_lesson] += student_number
        else:
            lesson[student_name][student_lesson] = student_number

print(json.dumps(lesson, indent=2, sort_keys=True))

# lesson is a nested dict():
# lesson['Jade']['English'] or
# lesson.get('Jade').get('English')
```

Which yields:

```py
{
  "Jade": {    
    "English": 4,    
    "French": 4
  }
}
```

## Without using json and defaultdict

```py
csvlist = [['name','grade','lesson','number'],
           ['Jade','8','English',1],
           ['Jade','8','English',3],
           ['Jade','8','French',4],
           ['James','7','Maths',3]]

names_dic = {'Jade':{'skip':2,'gpa':8.34}, 
             'Mark':{'skip':16,'gpa':5.67}}


lesson = dict()
min_grade = 8

for student in csvlist[1:]:
    student_name = student[0]
    student_grade = student[1]
    student_lesson = student[2]
    student_number = student[3]

    # if the key exists add the number
    if float(student_grade) >= min_grade:
        if not lesson.get(student_name, False):
            lesson[student_name] = {}
        try:
            lesson[student_name][student_lesson] += student_number
        except:
            lesson[student_name][student_lesson] = student_number


# printing
for student_k, student_v in lesson.items():
    print(student_k)
    for student_lesson in student_v.items():
         print(student_lesson)
    print()
```

Which yields:

```py
'Jade'
('English', 4)
('French', 4)
```

Comment: This works great, but is there a way to only include grade 8 students?

Comment: I will put the condition == 8, if you want you can change to >=8 or >8

Comment: I don't know why but, I tried and I still get all the students

Comment: I added the condition == 8 (`if float(student_grade) == min_grade:`), so only students with grade 8 will be added. The grade is taken from the csvlist right?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using json and collections?

Comment: I used json just to pretty print. As for collections, you can create a dict() for each level. Check the updated answer.

Comment: The problem with json is that I have to work with the data in the nested dictionary, but the type of json is string. Thank you for the second answer

Comment: Sorry again, I'm trying to understand why you put ```if not lesson.get(student_name, False):
            lesson[student_name] = {}``` I know the code doesn't work without it, but I just have issues understanding what it does. Also the `try` and `except`, couldn't I just say something like ```if float(student_grade) >= min_grade:
                                                lesson[student_name][student_lesson] += student_number``` ?

Comment: You can't evaluate directly using `if float(student_grade) >= min_grade: lesson[student_name][student_lesson] += student_number`because the subdicts don't exist yet, that's why I used `defaultdict` in the first example since it takes care of this exception. So I had to use `if not lesson.get(student_name, False)` to create the subdict if not existent.

Comment: As for the `try except` this is a "pythonic way" to do things: EAFP (easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) coding style. Try to run your `if float(student_grade) >= min_grade: lesson[student_name][student_lesson] += student_number` and you will see  a key error, the first run of `try` will give a `key error` because you're trying to access the key `['English']` by doing: `lesson['Jade']['English'] (here is OK) = lesson['Jade']['English']  (here is the problem) + student_number`. You're trying to add a non existing previous ['English']. Ex: `a = a + 1` (what is the value of `a`?)